# Makefile issues with interactive shells started as a target

Tags: macos, terminal, make, makefile

Currently having a weird problem:

Got a Makefile to get some handy shortcuts inside a Project:

```
shell:
    docker exec -it  $(web) sh
    ...
```

..which basically invokes an interactive shell inside a Docker Container.
This runs well on a Linux System.

On an OS X ( yosemite ) Terminal I only get some kind of a PTY (no echo, wrong CR, ...)

You can break this down to the following, less complex Makefile:

```
shell:
      bash
```

Invoked with

```
make shell
```

works on Linux, does not work on OS X :/

Any Ideas to get this working on OS X?

BTW.: stty reports no width and columns in the OS X case.

Answer (score 2):

Found it. Was nothing regarding bash, but the old gnu make version that ships with os x - which seems to have problems piping an interactive shell.

```
brew install homebrew/dupes/make
```

and using gmake afterwards fixed it...

Comment: homebrew/dupes was deprecated. You can now install `gmake` with `brew install make`.